# How to output left and right block indexes in JumpSearch in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to output left and right indexes of the block in *jump search* algorithm, but I don't really know how to do it. Do you have any idea? The last block may be shorter so probably left border is going to be shorter than the others, so I can really picture a solution. When I'm declaring a new variable and I'm trying to update it in a loop, then outside of the loop it still has the old value and I really don't know why.

My code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int target = scanner.nextInt();
        jumpSearch(array,target);
    }

    public static int jumpSearch(int[] array, int target) {
        int currentRight = 0;
        int prevRight = 0;

        // If array is empty, the element is not found
        if (array.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Check the first element
        if (array[currentRight] == target) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Calculating the jump length over array elements
        int jumpLength = (int) Math.sqrt(array.length);

        // Finding a block where the element may be present
        while (currentRight < array.length - 1) {

            // Calculating the right border of the following block
            currentRight = Math.min(array.length - 1, currentRight + jumpLength);

            if (array[currentRight] >= target) {
                break; // Found a block that may contain the target element
        }
        prevRight = currentRight; // update the previous right block border

        // If the last block is reached and it cannot contain the target value => not found
        if ((currentRight == array.length - 1) && target > array[currentRight]) {
            return -1;
        }

        /* Doing linear search in the found block */
        // backwardSearch(array, target, prevRight, currentRight);

        return 0;
    }

    public static int backwardSearch(int[] array, int target, int leftExcl, int rightIncl) {
        for (int i = rightIncl; i > leftExcl; i--) {
            if (array[i] == target) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jump-search/

Comment: Not really, i think this code is more complicated than mine, and i can't find a place where i can output block indexes

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what you mean by _output block indexes_.

Comment: I mean, I want to output left and right index of the block where the target is, and I don't have an idea how to do it, especially that I want to output left and right index in one line.

Comment: _output_ means to me _print to screen_, as in `System.out.println()`, but I don't think that's what you mean, so I still don't understand.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. When I'm inputting a number, I want to achieve left and right indexes of the block in which this number is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code from the example that I linked to in my comment to your question. I added three lines to it. I added a the following comment to each line I added.

```
// ADDED THIS LINE
```

---

```java
public class JumpSearch 
{ 
    public static int jumpSearch(int[] arr, int x) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length; 
  
        // Finding block size to be jumped 
        int step = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); 
  
        // Finding the block where element is 
        // present (if it is present) 
        int prev = 0; 
        while (arr[Math.min(step, n)-1] < x) 
        { 
            prev = step; 
            step += (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)); 
            if (prev >= n) 
                return -1; 
        } 
  
        // Doing a linear search for x in block 
        // beginning with prev.
        int left = prev; // ADDED THIS LINE
        int right = Math.min(step, n); // ADDED THIS LINE
        while (arr[prev] < x) 
        { 
            prev++; 
  
            // If we reached next block or end of 
            // array, element is not present. 
            if (prev == Math.min(step, n)) 
                return -1; 
        } 
  
        // If element is found 
        if (arr[prev] == x) {
            System.out.printf("Found %d between %d and %d%n", x, left, right); // ADDED THIS LINE
            return prev; 
        }
        return -1; 
    } 
  
    // Driver program to test function 
    public static void main(String [ ] args) 
    { 
        int arr[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 
                    34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610}; 
        int x = 55; 
  
        // Find the index of 'x' using Jump Search 
        int index = jumpSearch(arr, x); 
  
        // Print the index where 'x' is located 
        System.out.println("\nNumber " + x + 
                            " is at index " + index); 
    } 
}
```

When I run the above code, I get this output.

```
Found 55 between 8 and 12

Number 55 is at index 10
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thank you!